# Plotting a table using Row

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I want to plot the following table:

```
tst1 = 
  {0, 0, 0, 8, 15, 18, 19, 20, 25, 30, 28, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 11, 10, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.5} 
tst2 = Evaluate[{0, 0, 0, Row[Table[tst1[[i]], {i, 4, 25}], ","]}]
ListPlot[Table[{tst1[[i]], tst2[[i]]}, {i, 25}]]
```

The issue is that I want to have a list plot of a table essentially in the `tst2` form, not in the `tst1` form, but my code fails for `tst2`.

Can someone look at this and help me.

Comment: `tst2` is `{0, 0, 0, Row[{8, 15, 18, 19, 20, 25, 30, 28, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 11, 10, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.5}, ","]}`. So this fails `Table[{tst1[[i]], tst2[[i]]}, {i, 25}]` with "part does not exist". Please explain exactly what you are trying to to. "Plot a table with a 'Row' command" is not at all clear.

Comment: Sorry, that's just a title to indicate that if a Table has row command, why does the ListPlot fails to work. The given code is complete.

Comment: @SciJewel It *can't* work. The code doesn't make sense with Row in it. That's why we are asking what you're trying to do. How did the Row end up in there? What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: @MarcoB I'm going to guess that OP is looking for the functionality of `Splice` or `Join` to combine two lists. The Row makes it look like `tst1` has been spliced into `tst2`, but that's just an optical illusion. It should be `tst2 = Join[{0, 0, 0}, tst1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Table already puts it's element in a row. To build your Listplot, it looks lie you just need to Flatten.

```
 tst1 = {0, 0, 0, 8, 15, 18, 19, 20, 25, 30, 28, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 11, 10, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.5};
 tst2 = {0, 0, 0, Table[tst1[[i]], {i, 4, 25}]} // Flatten
 ListPlot[Table[{tst1[[i]], tst2[[i]]}, {i, 25}]]
```

Comment: This is what I really wanted. In this case I don't need Row which was suggested in another post for combining two such kind of tables. Flatten work this time, though initially I tried it, but was useless. Thanks